# Graph API Error: HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Graph API (version 4.50.0) to send through emails. All of a sudden to day I get the below inner expception error when sending mails.

HttpProtocolException: The HTTP/2 server reset the stream. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1).

Here is the code & IMage

```
public async Task<bool> SendGraphEmailAsync(Message email)
{
    var user = await _userProfileServ.GetCurrentUserAsync();
    var authRecords = await _externalAuthServ.GetUserExternalAuthenticationRecordsAsync(user);
    var azureAuth = authRecords.FirstOrDefault();

    if (azureAuth == null)
        return false;

    try
    {
        _graphClient.AuthenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", azureAuth.OAuthAccessToken);
        });

        //var outcome = await _graphClient.DeviceManagement..OnPremisesConnections["1234567890"].RunHealthChecks.PostAsync();
        
        await _graphClient.Me.SendMail(email).Request().PostAsync();// THE LINE THAT PRODUCES THE ERROR: 
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        //loging of erors
    }
    

    return false;
}
```

[image: Exception]

"_graphClient" service uses the GraphServiceClient class which inherits BaseClient of the Graph API package

Comment: As you haven't shared any code, it's impossible to provide help. Also, why is this tagged with Charts?

Comment: Your code looks good and the error message looks like to indicate a network issue per my understanding. Could you please try to run `var user = await _graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();` before the problematic line to see if graph API could load user information correctly? By the way, does your code work well before?

Comment: It worked perfectly before!!!
var user = await _graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync(); gets the correct info, and is not null.